# Scala Option type upper bound don't understand

Tags: scala, option-type, type-systems

I'm reading Functional Programming in Scala, and in chapter 04 the authors implement Option on their own. Now, when defining the function `getOrElse` they use an upper bound to restrict the type of `A` to a supertype (if a understood correctly)

So, the definition goes:

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {
   def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B = this match {
     case None => default
     case Some(a) => a
   }
}
```

So, when we have something like

```
val a = Some(4)
println(a.getOrElse(None)) => println prints a integer value
val b = None
println(b.getOrElse(Some(3)) => println prints a Option[Integer] value
```

`a` has type `Option[Int]`, so `A` would be type `Int`. `B` would be type `Nothing`. `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type. That means that `Option[Nothing]` is a subtype of `Option[Int]` (because of covariance), right?

But with `B >: A` we said that `B` has to be a supertype?! So how can we get an `Int` back? This is a bit confusing for me...

Anyone care to try and clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> That means that Option[Nothing] is a subtype of Option[Int] (because of covariance), right?

Correct. `Option[Nothing]` is an `Option[Int]`.

> But with B >: A we said that B has to be a supertype?! So how can we get an Int back?

It doesn't have to be a super-type. It just requires `A` as a *lower-bound*. Which means you can still pass `Int` to `getOrElse` if `A` is `Int`.

But that doesn't mean you can't pass instances of a sub-class. For instance:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B

scala> Option(new B)
res196: Option[B] = Some(B@661f82ac)

scala> res196.getOrElse(new C)
res197: B = B@661f82ac

scala> res196.getOrElse(new A)
res198: A = B@661f82ac

scala> res196.getOrElse("...")
res199: Object = B@661f82ac
```

I can still pass an instance of `C`, because `C` can be up-cast to `B`. I can also pass a type higher up the inheritance tree, and `getOrElse` will return that type, instead. If I pass a type that has nothing to do with the type contained in the `Option`, then the type with the least upper-bound will be inferred. In the above case, it's `Any`.

---

So why is the lower-bound there at all? Why not have:

```
def getOrElse[B <: A](default: => B): B
```

This won't work because `getOrElse` must either return the `A` that's contained in the `Option`, or the default `B`. But if we return the `A`, and `A` is not a `B`, so the type-bound is invalid. Perhaps if `getOrElse` returned `A`:

```
def getOrElse[B <: A](default: => B): A
```

This would work (if it were really defined that way), but you would be restricted by the type-bounds. So in my above example, you could only pass `B` or `C` to `getOrElse` on an `Option[B]`. In any case, this is not how it is in the standard library.

---

The standard library `getOrElse` allows you to pass anything to it. Say you have `Option[A]`. If we pass a sub-type of `A`, then it is up-cast to `A`. If we pass `A`, obviously this is okay. And if we pass some other type, then the compiler infers the least upper-bound between the two. In all cases, the type-bound `B >: A` is met.

Because `getOrElse` allows you to pass anything to it, many consider it very tricky. For example you could have:

```
val number = "blah"
// ... lots of code
val result = Option(1).getOrElse(number)
```

And this will compile. We'll just have an `Option[Any]` that will probably cause an error somewhere else down the line.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please provide an example of what type we wouldn't be able to pass to res196.getOrElse... currently, with this example, I don't see the point of having a lower bound. Or better to say, I now don't understand what it means for a type to be a lower bound...